# React native Accordion animation Bug

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-reanimated

So, I am trying to make accordion in react-native.
When I am opening & closing the acccordion.
The  is getting mounted/unmounted taking the space required & then animation is happening over the layout[image].
How can I fix this using react-native-reanimated ?
My code is like this

```
<Accordion layout={Layout.duration(1500)} style={{borderBottomWidth:1}}>
  <Header onPress={setOpenedMonths}/>
  {isOpen && <Content/>}
</Accordion>
```

Comment: I think you should implement custom height animation because the layout animation is buggy a bit. You can find a lot of open issues in the reanimated repo.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
    import {
      Text,
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      LayoutAnimation,
      Platform,
      UIManager,
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from 'react-native';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
    export default class ExpandCollapse extends PureComponent {
      constructor() {
        super();
    
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
        }
      }
    
      changeLayout = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        this.props.onOpenBond();
      };
    
      render() {
        let {data} = this.props;
    
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.btnTextHolder}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                onPress={this.changeLayout}
                style={styles.Btn}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                    borderRadius: 15,
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}>
                  <Icon
                    name={
                      this.props.isOpen
                        ? 'chevron-up-outline'
                        : 'chevron-down-outline'
                    }
                    size={24}
                    color="#fff"
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Text style={styles.titleText}>Rating Agency</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.contentText}>
                    {typeof data.agency == 'string'
                      ? data.agency
                      : data.agency.agency_name}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View
                style={{
                  height: this.props.isOpen ? null : 0,
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                }}>
                <View style={[styles.Btn, {paddingVertical: 0}]}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      borderRadius: 15,
                    }}></View>
                  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Rating</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.contentText}>
                      {data.rating_name != undefined
                        ? data.rating_name
                        : data.rating}{' '}
                      {data.outlook == 1
                        ? 'Positive'
                        : data.outlook == 2
                        ? 'Stable'
                        : data.outlook == 3
                        ? 'Negative'
                        : ''}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.Btn, {paddingVertical: 0, marginTop: 10}]}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      borderRadius: 15,
                    }}></View>
                  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Remarks</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.contentText}>
                      {data.remark == '' ? '-' : data.remark}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View
                  style={[styles.Btn, {paddingVertical: 0, marginVertical: 10}]}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      borderRadius: 15,
                    }}></View>
                  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Rating Rationale</Text>
    
                    <Text
                      onPress={() => {
                        if (
                          data.filename == '' ||
                          data.filename == undefined ||
                          data.filename == null
                        ) {
                          return;
                        }
                        this.props.openPdfView();
                      }}
                      style={[
                        styles.contentText,
                        {
                          color: 'green',
    
                          textDecorationLine:
                            data.filename == '' ? 'none' : 'underline',
                        },
                      ]}>
                      {data.filename == '' ? '-' : 'Pdf File'}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    
      titleText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#AAA',
        marginLeft: 10,
    
        flex: 1,
      },
      contentText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#aaa',
        marginLeft: 10,
        flex: 1,
      },
    
      btnTextHolder: {
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      },
    
      Btn: {
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
    });
```